# Error when manage docker as a non-root user

Tags: docker, command-line

I want to use docker without sudo and follow the guidance from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo). And here is what I did:
1.

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

and it showed

```
groupadd: group 'docker' already exists
```

2.

```
sudo gpasswd -a <username> docker
```

and it showed

```
Adding user <username> to group docker
```

3.

```
newgrp docker
```

and it showed the error:

```
newgrp: failed to crypt password with previous salt:invalid argument
```

I have tried to find more about this error,

```
newgrp: failed to crypt password with previous salt:invalid argument
```

but there is very limited information on the internet.

What leads to this error?

Comment: After `sudo gpasswd -a <username> docker` you need to logout and log-in back again. To verfiy whether docker commands are running with sudo for non-root user.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48568172/596285

Comment: You need to logout and log-in back again after add gpasswd for your user.

Answer (score 11):

If someone has same error try:

1. sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
2. newgrp docker

This worked for me

Comment: Seems the two commands must be run in the same shell. This worked for me.