# How to run docker in docker in Container-optimized OS on Compute Engine VM on Google Cloud?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I have a master container instance (Node.js) that runs some tasks in a temporary worker docker container.

The base image used is `node:8-alpine` and the entrypoint command executes with user `node` (non-root user).

I tried running my container with the following command:

```sh
docker run \
-v /tmp/box:/tmp/box \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
ifaisalalam/ide-taskmaster
```

But when the nodejs app tries running a docker container, permission denied error is thrown - the app can't read `/var/run/docker.sock` file.

Accessing this container through `sh` and running `ls -lha /var/run/docker.sh`, I see that the file is owned by `root:412`. That's why my `node` user can't run docker container.

The `/var/run/docker.sh` file on host machine is owned by `root:docker`, so I guess the `412` inside the container is the docker group ID of the host machine.

---

I'd be glad if someone could provide me an workaround to run docker from docker container in Container-optimized OS on GCE.

---

The source Git repository link of the image I'm trying to run is - https://github.com/ifaisalalam/ide-taskmaster

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker.sock permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568172/docker-sock-permission-denied)

Comment: @ASLIM I don't think so. I am facing this issue on GCP only. On my machine, everything is working as a charm. My question is related with running docker from within a docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following command into my start-up script of the host machine solves the problem:

```sh
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

I am just not sure if this would be a secure workaround for an app running in production.

**EDIT:**

This answer suggests another approach that might also work - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47272481/11826776

Also, you may read this article - https://denibertovic.com/posts/handling-permissions-with-docker-volumes/