# Unable to use docker with Bamboo (Permission denied)

Tags: docker, bamboo

I am trying to run a docker command in Bamboo, but I got a permission denied error:

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

I already made sure that `docker.sock` has the right permission and added the user `bamboo` and (just to be sure) `bamboo-server` to the docker group.

```
srw-rw----  1 root     docker      0 Feb 28  2019 docker.sock=

cat /etc/group | grep docker
docker:x:120:bamboo-server,bamboo
```

So all settings that help to solve the issue for others seem to be set, but I am stil receiving the error. Any ideas what more I can do to fix this?

**Edit:**

I have tried some more things regarding permission, but even after changing the permission to *777* Bamboo keeps failing and the error is the same:

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

This makes me think that it might not be a permission problem at all. But I can't figure out what the actual problem is. Any ideas where to look?

Comment: you will have to make these kind of changes in your pipeline
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568172/docker-sock-permission-denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was restarting the Bamboo. After the restart all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the bamboo agent is probably all you need to refresh the user permissions, group ID, etc.  All of the plans that are executed are children of the bamboo-agent, and group settings are only refreshed on a fresh login.  If the bamboo-agent doesn't restart, it and all children will retain the old group settings.

On Centos, I do

```
sudo systemctl restart bamboo-agent
```

on the machine that is having the trouble, after modifying /etc/groups (for example).