# docker.sock permission denied while running jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have the following **jenkinsfile** which is giving the error below.

```
node {
    docker.withRegistry("https://001.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-tooling") {
        docker.image('my-tooling:deploy-agent_0.0.3')
                .inside("-v /var/lib/jenkins/.ivy2:/home/jenkins/.ivy2", {
...
}
```

Error

> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/my-tooling:deploy-agent_0.0.3/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

I see lots of [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568172/docker-sock-permission-denied) suggesting to run `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER` but as I'm not running this locally and don't have access to the vm, because it's all infra-as-code how can I add this to the jenkinsfile?

I've tried to add it like this,

```
node {
    try {
        stage('set permissions') {
            sh "sudo usermod -aG docker jenkins"
            //also tried "sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock"
        }
    } finally {
        echo 'Unable to set permissions'
    }
    ...
}
```

But I'm not able to run sudo as I get the error..

```
We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things: 
#1) Respect the privacy of others.
#2) Think before you type.
#3) With great power comes great responsibility.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
script returned exit code 1
```

Comment: Is docker installed on the machine ? And the docker plugin in jenkins ?
How is installed jenkins (container or on VM) ? Because if you can't add the user in the docker group I don't know if its possible.
Maybe try with `--privileged` or `-u root` in your`.inside()`

Comment: Just tried `.inside("-v /var/lib/jenkins/.ivy2:/home/jenkins/.ivy2 --privileged")` and `.inside("-u root -v /var/lib/jenkins/.ivy2:/home/jenkins/.ivy2")` both gave same error. Thanks

Comment: And with both ?

Comment: yep, same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you arrive to this question of stack overflow because you receive this message from docker, but you don't use jenkins, most probably the error is the same: your unprivileged user does not belong to the docker group.

You can do:

sudo usermod -a -G docker [user]
Insert your user name where [user] is.

You can check it was successful by doing grep docker /etc/group and see something like this:

docker:x:998:[user]
in one of the lines.

Then change your users group ID to docker:

newgrp docker
Finally, log out and log in again

Comment: Where do I run `sudo usermod -aG docker jenkins`? You've just given me what I see in the other answers.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.