# Run docker without sudo in ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu

Yes I have followed steps provided here https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/ and https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/ and also checked this thread [docker.sock permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568172/docker-sock-permission-denied)

But still getting the below problem when docker is run without sudo in *Ubuntu 18.04*

```
docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

It is rather frustrating as I tried multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked fine after deleting the below entry in .bashrc
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock

I'm not sure how that line made it into .bashrc

Feel so stupid now. Anyway thanks!